# How can i have the generic api response to all of my api in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have done my research on internet about to having generic response format for all my apis in .net core like this

```
{
  payload: [// all data goes here] || {}, // it could be any combination of Array of object of custom types, object of custom type, boolean value
  errorMessage: // optional, in case of error,
  metaData: {} // optional, in case of get apis 
}
```

How can i have this kind of generic response for all apis?

**Note: I also want some suggestions that what other details should be in the api response as a best practise?**

Comment: Create a base class with those properties?

Comment: 1- Can you create a example for me? i am new to .net core.
2- Any suggestion of about, what other details should be in the response for all apis?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for generic result with field `Value` if your endpoint returns some data and without field `Value` if not:

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    protected Result()
    {
    }

    public static Result Success()
    {
        return new Result
        {
            IsSuccess = true
        };
    }

    public static Result<T> Success<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Result<T>
        {
            Value = value,
            IsSuccess = true
        };
    }

    public static Result Error(ErrorModel error, string requestId)
    {
        return Error(new [] { error }, requestId);
    }

    public static Result Error(ErrorModel[] errors, string requestId)
    {
        return new ErrorResult
        {
            Errors = errors,
            RequestId = requestId,
            IsSuccess = false
        };
    }

    public static Result<T> Error<T>(string[] errorCodes, string requestId)
    {
        return Error<T>(errorCodes.Select(x => new ErrorModel(x)).ToArray(), requestId);
    }

    public static Result<T> Error<T>(ErrorModel error, string requestId)
    {
        return Error<T>(new [] { error }, requestId);
    }

    public static Result<T> Error<T>(ErrorModel[] errors, string requestId)
    {
        return new ErrorResult<T>
        {
            Errors = errors,
            RequestId = requestId,
            IsSuccess = false
        };
    }



    [DataMember(Name = "success")]
    public virtual bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

}

public class ErrorResult : Result
{
    [DataMember(Name = "errors")]
    public virtual ErrorModel[] Errors { get; set; } = null!;

    [DataMember(Name = "requestId")]
    public string RequestId { get; set; } = null!;
}

[DataContract]
public class Result<T> : Result
{
    [DataMember(Name = "result")]
    public T? Value { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class ErrorResult<T> : Result<T>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "errors")]
    public virtual ErrorModel[] Errors { get; set; } = null!;


    [DataMember(Name = "requestId")]
    public string RequestId { get; set; } = null!;
}
```